Consumer doesn't rebuild while the state changes using provider
I worked on the app where the notification is publish from the app the app will detect that the notification is arrived and it has to show the flash-message, Here I used FCMApi class as provider and whenever the _showFlashMessage changes it will have to show that flash-message but it didn't showed up so what is the problem here? here is main.dart file code.
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flash/flash.dart';
import 'package:flash/flash_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/fcm_api.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/notification_provider.dart';

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FCMApi().initNotification();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => NotificationProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: FCMApi()),
        // ChangeNotifireProvider(create: (_) => FCMApi()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: CampaignListScreen(),
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CampaignListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Campaigns'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<FCMApi>(builder: (ctx, api, _) {
        print('rebuilding........................');
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          if (api.getShowFlashMessage) {
            print('showing message.......................');
            context.showFlash<bool>(
              barrierDismissible: true,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
              builder: (context, controller) => FlashBar(
                controller: controller,
                forwardAnimationCurve: Curves.easeInCirc,
                reverseAnimationCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
                position: FlashPosition.top,
                indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                icon: Icon(Icons.tips_and_updates_outlined),
                title: Text('titler'),
                content: Text('body'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: controller.dismiss, child: Text('Cancel')),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => controller.dismiss(true),
                      child: Text('Ok'))
                ],
              ),
            );
            api.messageFalse();
          } 
        });
        return Consumer<NotificationProvider>(
          builder: (ctx, data, _) => ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => {
                  navigatorKey.currentState!.push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => HomeScreen(
                          page: data.getNotification[i].page.toString(),
                          imageUrl:
                              data.getNotification[i].imageUrl.toString())))
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(data.getNotification[i].title.toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(data.getNotification[i].body.toString()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            itemCount: data.getNotification.length,
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

and here is FCMApi.dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:push_notification/main.dart';

class FCMApi extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  bool _showFlashMessage = false;

  bool get getShowFlashMessage {
    return _showFlashMessage;
  }

  void messageFalse() {
    _showFlashMessage = false;
  }

  void messageTrue() {
    _showFlashMessage = true;
    notifyListeners();
    print('notify.................');
  }

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    final FCMToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('Token: $FCMToken');
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(foregroundNotificationHandler);
  }

  Future<void> foregroundNotificationHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print(message.notification!.title);
    print(message.notification!.body);
    print(message.data);

    messageTrue();
  }
}

